# Why does @EnableWebMvc break the JSON deserialization?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, lombok

In my sample application I have a simple @RestController controller:

```
package app.springtest.api.book;

import app.springtest.service.BookService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/book")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class BookController {

    private final BookService bookService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity upsertBook(@Valid @RequestBody BookRequest bookRequest) {
        final BookResponse response = bookService.addBook(bookRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
}
```

It consumes this Json object.

```
package app.springtest.api.book;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.Wither;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))
@Wither
public class BookRequest {

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(value = "isbn", required = true)
    private final String isbn;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(value = "name", required = true)
    private final String name;

    @JsonProperty(value = "author", required = true)
    @NotBlank
    private final String author;

}
```

There is nothing special, just Lombok generating some boilerplate code.

However, when I add `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to the application configuration, the post request fails and returns this error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1557494204976,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/api/v1/book"
}
```

and there is following error in log:

> .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson
>   deserialization for type [[simple type, class
>   app.springtest.api.book.BookRequest]]:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid
>   type definition for type `app.springtest.api.book.BookRequest`:
>   Argument #0 has no property name, is not Injectable: can not use as
>   Creator [constructor for app.springtest.api.book.BookRequest,
>   annotations: {interface
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)}]

How can it be, that the deserialization stops working?

Edit: And why does the `@RestController` class work in the situation, when the `@EnableWebMvc` is not present? Isn't this the annotation, that makes MVC work in Spring?

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem a couple of days ago. My problem was sold by adding the `@JsonProperty` annotations on the constructor arguments (I had to actually write the constructor and not use Lombok). I still don't know though what causes that behavior.

Comment: @Sofo Gial: That works, thank you! If I find out, what exactly goes on, I'll put it here.

Comment: Apparently it's a known issue with Lombok: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1612

Comment: There is one more thing, that seems strange to me. Why does the `@RestController` class work in the situation, when the `@EnableWebMvc` is not present? Isn't this the annotation, that makes MVC work in Spring?

Comment: Since you are using Spring Boot, when you add the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, `@EnableWebMvc` comes with it out of the box. You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51008465/6162023