# WebMvcConfigurer not working in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I changed my perfectly working controller class which were just doing the purpose of view resolution like so:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

@GetMapping("/signup")
public String signupPage() {
    return "signup";
}

@GetMapping("/login")
public String loginPage() {
    return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/dashboard")
public String dashboardPage() {
    return "dashboard";
}

@GetMapping("/logout")
public String logoutPage() {
    return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

To a class extending WebMvcConfigurer, which had all the view resolvers like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ViewConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/signup").setViewName("signup");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/dashboard").setViewName("dashboard");
    registry.addViewController("/logout").setViewName("redirect:/");
}
```

This felt a lot more concise, and clean.

But this is giving me 405 Method Not Allowed error, whenever I try to load any  of these pages. Why is this happening? Does spring boot not support WebMvcConfigurer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/), under the spring mvc section you can use WebMvcConfigurer, but you do not need to do @EnableWebMvc

So you should remove the @EnableWebMvc annotation!

```
@Configuration
// @EnableWebMvc Remove this!
public class ViewConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/signup").setViewName("signup");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/dashboard").setViewName("dashboard");
    registry.addViewController("/logout").setViewName("redirect:/");
}
```

Comment: When should the @EnableWebMvc annotation be used then?

Comment: @YeetCoder with this configuration you just redirect to index page. You don't do logout.

Comment: @JeetRoy EnableWebMvc is not required for spring boot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008382/why-spring-boot-application-doesnt-require-enablewebmvc