# Spring boot JsonMappingException: Object is null

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a @RestController that returns net.sf.json.JSONObject:

```
@PostMapping("/list")
public JSONObject listStuff(HttpServletRequest inRequest, HttpServletResponse inResponse) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    ...
    return json;
}
```

When JSONObject contains null reference, the following exception is thrown:

```
Could not write JSON: Object is null; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Object is null (through reference chain: net.sf.json.JSONObject[\"list\"]->net.sf.json.JSONArray[0]->net.sf.json.JSONObject[\"object\"]->net.sf.json.JSONNull[\"empty\"])"
```

This is the legacy code that we are now cleaning up and at some point we will get rid of explicit JSON manipulations, but this will be a huge change, for now I would like to just get rid of the exception.
I tried with following solutions:

1. Define `Include.NON_NULL` in Spring's Object Mapper - so this piece of code in my `WebMvcConfigurationSupportClass`:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) 
{
    ObjectMapper webObjectMapper = objectMapper.copy();
    webObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(webObjectMapper)); 
}
```

2. Setting following property in application.yml:
   `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null`
3. Checking the version of `com.fasterxml.jackson` - the only found in the dependency tree is 2.9.7.

None of the above helped.

Any suggestions on how to tell Spring to ignore null values in net.sf.json.JSONObjects?

Comment: have you also tried the `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_ABSENT`? Note that this is `NON_ABSENT` and not `NON_NULL`

Comment: Tried your suggestion with both NON_ABSENT and NON_EMPTY - still not working.

Comment: What is the name and version of library from which `net.sf.json.JSONObject` class comes?

Comment: `<groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
<artifactId>json-lib</artifactId><version>2.4</version>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the ideal solution, but rather a workaround. As overriding default mapper/converter behavior didn't work, instead I changed the structure of my JSONObject, so added following line during its generation:

`listElt.put("object", "");`

which produces: 
`{
  "list" : [ {
    "object" : ""
  } ]
}`

This is fine only if I am not interested in the value of this field - and I am not.
I personally prefer @Michał Ziober's solution - it is elegant and generic. Unfortunately doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

`Include.NON_NULL` does not work because `JSONNull` represents `null` but it is not `null` *per se*. From [documentation](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/index.html):

> JSONNull is equivalent to the value that JavaScript calls null, whilst
>   Java's null is equivalent to the value that JavaScript calls
>   undefined.

This object is implemented as a `Singleton` which has two methods: `isArray` and `isEmpty` where `isEmpty` is problematic because throws exception. Below snippet shows it's implementation:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
   throw new JSONException("Object is null");
}
```

The best way is to define `NullSerializer` for `JSONNull` type. Below example shows how we can configure that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONNull;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule netSfJsonModule = new SimpleModule("net.sf.json");
        netSfJsonModule.addSerializer(JSONNull.class, NullSerializer.instance);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(netSfJsonModule);

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.accumulate("object", JSONNull.getInstance());

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.add(object);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.accumulate("list", jsonArray);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(json));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "list" : [ {
    "object" : null
  } ]
}
```

See also:

1. [Maven: missing net.sf.json-lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173214/maven-missing-net-sf-json-lib)
2. [How do you override the null serializer in Jackson 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101506/how-do-you-override-the-null-serializer-in-jackson-2-0)

Comment: Sounds reasonably, though it didn't help. I've added a configuration class: `@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
 
 @Bean
 @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
  
  SimpleModule netSfJsonModule = new SimpleModule("net.sf.json");
        netSfJsonModule.addSerializer(JSONNull.class, NullSerializer.instance);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(netSfJsonModule);
        return mapper;`

Comment: @Tirlipirli, I am not sure this bean will be used. Have you tried to configure it with `configureMessageConverters` method like in your question? I know it could be a problem with rgistering custom `ObjectMapper`. Please, try: [In Spring Boot, adding a custom converter by extending MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter seems to overwrite the existing converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761845/in-spring-boot-adding-a-custom-converter-by-extending-mappingjackson2httpmessag)

Comment: @Tirlipirli  or [Custom Jackson deserializer does not get registered in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891911/custom-jackson-deserializer-does-not-get-registered-in-spring) or [Customizing HttpMessageConverters with Spring Boot and Spring MVC](https://dzone.com/articles/customizing). I know that sometimes it is a problem with overriding when `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` already exists on converters list.

Comment: Looks like `objectMapper()` method is called - with no results and `configureMessageConverters(...)` is not called at all.

Comment: @Tirlipirli, that's strange. Could you try with setting `consumes` and `produces` to `application/json`?

Comment: If you mean mediaType then this is not helping.

Comment: @Tirlipirli, it is definitely a problem with customising `ObjectMapper`. I suggest to change this controller to return `String`: `public String listStuff`. Inject object mapper and serialise it manually in a method before returning.